# How do I properly implement Bootstrap carousel in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, spacebars

I'm migrating some code to blaze and have hit a problem with the bootstrap carousel that I can't seem to get over.

I had the following pre blaze to set one of the carousel items active to kick the whole thing off

```
<div class="item {{#if active_sponsor}}active{{/if}}">
```

As documented, this no longer works with blaze, so I've tried modifying it to the only thing I can think of which is

```
{{#if active_sponsor}}
  <div class="item {{#if active_sponsor}}active{{/if}}">
{{else}}
  <div class="item">
{{/if}}
```

This all lives within an {{each sponsors}} block.

Sadly, this fails to run with an error saying unexpected {{else}} (or, if I remove the {{else}} unexpected {{/if}}

What's the correct way to do this. I'm using exactly the same pattern earlier to change a

Comment: Are you sure the first form is not working? That should still be valid, and is working for me. I think what you're referring to in the Blaze guide is that *valueless* attributes like `selected` and `checked` can not be defined like `<option value="val" {{#if isSelected}}selected{{/if}}>` anymore.

Comment: I agree with @sbking that the first form should be fine. Regarding the second option, have you tried `{{#if active_sponsor}}
  <div class="item active">
{{else}}
  <div class="item">
{{/if}}`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. You are correct skbing, the first version is now working (just did a mrt update so must have been something there).
For info Tobold, the code you have is infact what I was trying, my bad typing sorry. This is the code that was not allowing me to run for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Using Blaze" on github :

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

So you should use this form instead, assuming that active_sponsor is the property to look for in the current data context.

```
Template.whatever.helpers({
    isActive:function(){
        return this.active_sponsor?"active":"";
    }
});

<div class="item {{isActive}}">
</div>
```